# python datetime difference in days and hours

Tags: python, datetime

I want to compare two datetime instances and show the how many days and hours that differs. Now I do that with .days and it does seem to work but pylint complains about it.

Is there a better way to do it since pylint complains about it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""A test of time differences"""

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

REF_DATE = datetime.strptime("2015-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")

def main():
    """Main function"""
    today = datetime.now()
    tdiff = today - REF_DATE
    print("Difference is %d days %d hours" % (tdiff.days, tdiff.seconds/3600))

main()
```

This is the output I get from pylint:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module test_timedelta
E: 12,52: Instance of 'datetime' has no 'days' member (but some types could not be inferred) (maybe-no-member)
E: 12,64: Instance of 'datetime' has no 'seconds' member (but some types could not be inferred) (maybe-no-member)
W:  4, 0: Unused import timedelta (unused-import)


...
```

Comment: Pylint is not always right, like in this case. Please note the "maybe" at the end of the line.

Comment: Unless the complaint comes from the Python interpreter and includes the word "traceback," you can ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import the `timedelta` name; you can safely remove it from your import list:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Just because subtracting `datetime` objects produces objects of that type does not mean you need to import the type itself.

As for the other lines, `pylint` simply is making a wrong inference. You can safely ignore those lines. You can disable that warning by using a comment for the `print()` line:

```
tdiff = today - REF_DATE
print("Difference is %d days %d hours" % (
    tdiff.days, tdiff.seconds/3600))  #pylint: disable=E1103
```

You can apply the comment to the whole function too:

```
def main():
    """Main function"""
    #pylint: disable=E1103
    today = datetime.now()
    tdiff = today - REF_DATE
    print("Difference is %d days %d hours" % (tdiff.days, tdiff.seconds/3600))
```